# trouble deleting table row in ruby rails with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, database-migration

trying to remove a table row by command

```
rails g migration RemoveSource_AccountFromPosts source_account:multiset
```

which creates a migration:

```
class RemoveSourceAccountFromPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :posts, :source_account, :multiset
  end
end
```

but when I rake, I get this error

```
-- remove_column(:posts, :source_account, :multiset)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClassC:/Sites/jeepjig/db/migrate/20150322155456_remove_source_account_from_posts
.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error here. What version of ruby, and what version of rails?

Comment: rails  '4.1.8'  ruby 2.1.5